# Optionally not printing page number citations using Biblatex and Biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

my question: Is it possible to optionally leave page number citations out when compiling a document? For Example when I write `\parencite[see][225-226]{7.01:1}`. I would like the corresponding citation to look like sth. "(see Herbst-Damm & Kulik, 2005)".

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english, american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-apa-test-references.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite[see][225-226]{7.01:1}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum \parencites[see][143-168]{7.01:13a}[226]{7.01:1}.

    \printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

Is this possible? Maybe be using a macro (I have no experience programming them).

Comment: Why don't you just write `\parencite[see][]{7.01:1}` if you don't want the pages to show. If that's not acceptable, what condition would you like to check for to determine whether to print the page number or not?

Comment: I want to write the page numbers for my personal references but some journals dont want them. So I would like an option to not print the page number citations. As I have no macro knowledge: Maybe a simple NoPageCitations=True???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
 \renewbibmacro*{postnote}{}
```

but this will naturally affect all cite commands.

If only `\parencite` should be change you should add this to your document:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens] %from apa.cbx
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {}%removed `\usebibmacro{postnote}
```

Comment: '\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{}' works, thank you.